# Get list of answers per city

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this db:

Users-table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | city_id |
+----+---------+
```

> city_id -> references id on city

Cities-table:

```
+----+------+
| id | city |
+----+------+
```

Answers-table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
```

> user_id -> references id on users

Now I want a query with this result:

```
+-----------+--------+
| City-name | amount |
+-----------+--------+
| New York  | 500    |
+-----------+--------+
```

I tried several joins, count, dinstincts but no success. Think it should be quite easy but didnt manage to do it.

My query:

```
SELECT cities.name, COUNT(answers.id) FROM answers
JOIN users ON users.id = answers.user_id
JOIN cities on users.city_id = cities.id
```

but gives me only 1 city..

Comment: Show us your query. And what means 500 (a total ?) ?

Comment: How did you get the column `amount`?

Comment: @kmas 500 answers in that city

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `GROUP BY cities.name`

```
SELECT cities.name, COUNT(answers.id) FROM answers
JOIN users ON users.id = answers.user_id
JOIN cities on users.city_id = cities.id
GROUP BY cities.name
```

This will tell MySQL that you want the COUNT to be grouped by cities. Without this, mysql will group everything together and count it all.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aggregating to get a count, etc. So something like:

```
SELECT      COALESCE(c.city, '<Unknown>') AS Cityname,
            COUNT(a.id) AS amount

FROM        Answers AS a

LEFT JOIN   Users AS u
    ON      a.user_id = u.id

LEFT JOIN   Cities AS c
    ON      u.city_id = c.id

GROUP BY    c.city
```